# bad directive error when converting string to_datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've got the following line of code

```
df['Sent Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Sent Date'], format = '%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p')
```

trying to convert these sort of strings to datetime
`1/1/2021  2:20:00 PM`

I get the following error

> '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p'

Also tried

```
import datetime
df['Sent Date'] = datetime.strptime(df['Sent Date'], '%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p')
```

and got the error

> 'module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

From viewing other questions/answers I thought one of these approaches would work ...

Comment: just let pandas to_datetime infer the format; e.g. `pd.to_datetime("1/1/2021 2:20:00 PM")` works fine for me. Btw. platform specific parsing directives like `'%-m` should not be needed anyway; `%m` should parse `01` and `1`.

Comment: Pandas expects the format string to contain field specifiers such as `%Y` or `%m`.  But you gave it `%-`, which is an unknown format.

Comment: No, _don't_ just let pandas infer the format, that's almost always a disaster. If you have mixed US ordering of `%m/%d/%Y` and `%d/%m/%Y` (or dates that could be either until some breaking point) it will actually just flip from its initial assumption. This is on the _most fundamental level_ of the assumptions it can make; if it can do this, it can do anything. And this is assuming all the data is clean in the first place

Comment: @MrFuppes "knowing what you're doing" or "hubris"? Don't underestimate what that parser can do! Or, that it'll even be stable from one release to the next :/

Comment: @roganjosh the `dayfirst` story is not a sectret, also element-wise format inference is mentioned in the docs. Besides, OP has a month-first pattern, otherwise I would have suggested to set `dayfirst=True`.

Comment: for your second error, replace `import datetime` by `from datetime import datetime` but it does not work because you can't pass a Series to `strptime`

Comment: @MrFuppes no secret, maybe, _to you_. But you're not advising you. I grant that you pointed the issue out in the same comment, but your "just let pandas to_datetime infer the format" is a broad brush that you haven't addressed, so they might just rely on the parser from now on for anything. And fixing the format string is surely preferable to just assuming the parser will work in all examples here?

Comment: @roganjosh addendum - you have a good point there. I'll be more precise with my advice in the future. Still, to me Python is the language I choose for convenience, and dateutil's parser (which pd.to_datetime uses and does not do magic) is a very convenient feature to me. Of course this comes at a cost, which I think can be reliability (which can be compensated by users' experience to some extent etc. etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'-'` is intended for output only (with `strftime`):

```
df['Sent Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sent Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print(df)

# Output
0   2021-01-01 14:20:00
Name: Sent Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Output:

```
>>> df['Sent Date'].dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y %-I:%M:%S %p')
0    1/1/2021 2:20:00 PM
Name: Sent Date, dtype: object
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sent Date': ['1/1/2021  2:20:00 PM']})
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: If I am trying to convert string to date, rather than date to time, what is the format for decimal month, day, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I get an error: time data '1/1/2021 14:20' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'

Comment: Now the format is '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'